# What is about digest cycle in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

Let we have the code in the control's method executed when, for example, we push a button

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.names = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
}, 0, false).then(function() {
    $scope.names.push('D');
})
```

in this case we will not see any changes at the screen because the digest cycle will not be running

But if we wrote this

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.names = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
}, 0, false).then(function() {
    $scope.names.push('D');

    return $q.when();
})
```

we will see changes because when we return promise the $Q provider decides to run the digest cycle. 
http://plnkr.co/edit/DqAzPBe37Qd9CU1ug8Pp?p=preview

Could you please explain me why, I don't understand the logic of this behavior. 
How to prevent this?

Comment: So what exactly you don't understand? You explicitly tell `$timeout` not to run new digest (note flag `false`) and then you wonder why it doesn't do it? In the second example even though `$timeout` won't trigger digest, `$q.when()` will do it in its turn.

Comment: @dfsq in the second case I do the same thing but digest cycle start to run

Comment: @Oleg `q.when` internally is an auto promise resolution, which causes angular to trigger the digest cycle via [$evalAsync](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L990).

Comment: @PSL yes I understand, but how to prevent this, because I don't need to run the cycle

Comment: So don't return `$q.when`?

Comment: Just dont do `$q.when`. `return` there actually is irrelevant, not sure why you are explicitly doing it. :)

Comment: @dfsq I wrote this code very simplifying the real case. What if I do the request in the code after the request I do other processing and so ...

Comment: @PSL let say I make a request to the server after some timeout and after receiving an answer I do some processing. And I don't need any digest cycle after all processing.

Comment: Why would you not want to run digest? Maybe there is better solution?

Comment: @Oleg Ok, i get it where you are going with this. I never had to do such stuff but one thing i can think of is since unfortunately `http` does not have suppress option, if at all you wan to do this (not sure why) you may have to use some other ajax libraries or even make your request by getting a fresh injector `angular.injector(['ng']).get('$http')`. Perhaps, you may want to look at the the actual cause for your performance issues (assuming that is why you are doing it).