# Does $q include an implicit digest/apply upon resolution/rejection of the promise chain?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angularjs-digest

Does `$q`include an implicit digest/apply upon resolution/rejection of the promise chain?

I have migrated a piece of code from `$q` to use `q` and a digest now appears to be missing resulting in different behavior. Why might this be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is about digest cycle in angular?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33479752/1048572)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more - it includes explicit as long as `QProvider` is defined like:

```
function $QProvider() {
  this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$exceptionHandler', function($rootScope, $exceptionHandler) {
    return qFactory(function(callback) {
      $rootScope.$evalAsync(callback); // ! $evalAsync()
    }, $exceptionHandler);
  }];
}
```

From this function declaration there is short way to method `.$evalAsync()` that for versin 1.2.28 looks like

```
$evalAsync: function(expr) {
    // if we are outside of an $digest loop and this is the first time we are scheduling async
    // task also schedule async auto-flush
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase && !$rootScope.$$asyncQueue.length) {
      $browser.defer(function() {
        if ($rootScope.$$asyncQueue.length) {
          $rootScope.$digest(); // ! $digest()
        }
      });
    }

    this.$$asyncQueue.push({scope: this, expression: expr});
},
```